# Arc Menu GNOME extension won't install in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I'm trying to install a GNOME shell extension called Arc Menu on my Ubuntu 17.10 machine. I do that through https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1228/arc-menu/.

When trying to install I get the ERROR red button.

How can I check what the error is and fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arc Menu depends on `gir1.2-gmenu-3.0` package. Install it first by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
```